how to display fractions using Greek letters (one on top of another) in unicode for R plot
I have the following MWE:
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)

set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(nu = c(rnorm(mean = 1, n = 100), rnorm(mean = 2, n = 50)), rho = c(rnorm(n = 50),rnorm(sd=2,n=100)), cl = c(rep("TRUE",100), rep("FALSE",50)))

names(df) <- c("\u03BD\u2081", "\u03C1\u2082", "cl")
tree <- rpart(cl~., data = df)
rpart.plot(tree, type = 4, extra = 0, branch.lty = 3, box.palette = "RdYlGn")

that gives me the image:

Which is great, except that i would like to display nu_1 / 4beta (in Greek notation), and in particular I think it would be clearer if I had the nu_1 over the 4beta. How do I display this sort of "overlaid" fraction?

Do you mean some kind of transliteration so that label ν₁ become nu_1, label ρ₂ becomes rho_2 etc? But where appears 4beta?

names(df) <- c("\u03BD\u2081/4\u03B2", "\u03C1\u2082", "cl") would give ν₁/4β. Is that what you want?

but i would like the nu_1 over the 4beta, in the sense that I have nu_1, under which is a line, and under that line is the 4beta. (I am not sure how to explain this kind of writing of a fraction).
